# Universal method of dealing with mobile multi-level navigation menus using HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have my html as follows:

```
<button id="hamburger-nav"></button>

<nav>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <button>Sub Nav Item 1</button>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <button>Sub Nav Item 2</button>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 10</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   <ul>
</nav>
```

This is a mobile menu that has a hamburger button that activates the "nav" on click. How do I get the index of the sub nav buttons so I can active their sibling "ul" sub sub menu? Granted all of this has to be done on the onclick method since it is a mobile menu.

I was hoping to have a universal method that could find the index of (this), i.e., the item that is clicked, and then get the corresponding "ul", instead of individually naming these and creating a massive, duplication of code for each menu section.

I would like to use plain old JavaScript as I am trying to cut down on the dependencies of jQuery, etc. Something along the lines of:

```
var menuButtons = document.querySelectorAll("nav > ul > li > button");
var submenu = document.querySelectorAll("nav > ul > li > ul");

menuButtons.onclick = myFunction(this);

function myFunction(v) {
   submenu[v].classList.add("open");
}
```

While I know this JavaScript doesn't work, accessing the index of the clicked button and opening its accompanying nav was my thought process. But perhaps I'm way of going about this.
Thank you in advance!